# Beautiful soup python 3 css troubles

Tags: python, css, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

```
import bs4
import requests
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}
url = 'http://twitter.com'
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
p = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
p.js-signup
```

When I put `p.js-signup` into the python shell it returns

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#29>", line 1, in <module>
p.js-signup
NameError: name 'signup' is not defined
```

I am quite new to this, so i'm not sure what I've done wrong, other css things that don't have '-' in them work fine

Comment: what is js-signup??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With python, `p.js-signup` is the opration `p.js` minus `signup`. It raises the error you have becaus `signup` does not exists.

```
NameError: name 'signup' is not defined
```

If you want to get the element `<js-lookup>` you have to use `find()` as explained in the [documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#finde).

If `js-lookup` is a CSS class: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#searching-by-css-class

Comment: Ah so like this you mean? `print(p.find(id='js-signup'))`

Answer (score 2):

The code `p.js-signup` means the following:

```
p.js - signup
```

So you are trying to subtract `signup` from `p.js`, but there is no variable `signup` in your code and that is what the error message is telling you.

Comment: I see, but when I SelectorGadget (http://selectorgadget.com/) to pick a css selector it gave me '.js-signup' so I don't know how to use that in bs4

Comment: If you want to select all elements with a specific class name use `p.find_all(class_='js-signup')`